# Java - Implementing a custom Iterable without using an inner-iterator class

Tags: java

I have the follow code

```
public class SBag<Item> implements BagInterface<Item>, Iterable<Item> {
```

And when I try to compile I get

```
SBag.java:12: error: SBag is not abstract and does not override abstract method
iterator() in Iterable
public class SBag<Item> implements BagInterface<Item>, Iterable<Item>{
       ^
 where Item is a type-variable:
Item extends Object declared in class SBag
```

My task is to implement Iterable without using an inner-iterator class, but I am unsure of how to do this because I get that error when compiling.  I have the followin methods add(), isFull(), toArray(), isEmpty(), getCurrentSize(), remove(), clear(), and toString().  The overall goal is to be able to use a for-each loop, but I am unsure of how to proceed from here.

Comment: The compile message says it all: you must have an `.iterator()` method, this is the contract of the `Iterable` interface. How you implement this method however is entirely up to you.

Comment: You must at least have a *separate* class to hold the state for that iteration. Otherwise you can't have more than one iteration going on at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

An Iterator as an inner class would look like this:

```
class MyIterable implements Iterable {
    public Iterator iterator() {
        return new Iterator() {
            public boolean hasNext() {...}
            public Object next() {...}
            void remove();
        }
    }
}
```

In contrast, an Iterator that's not an inner class might look more like:

```
class MyIterable implements Iterable {
    public Iterator iterator() {
        return new MyIterator();
    }
}

class MyIterator {
    public boolean hasNext() {...}
    public Object next() {...}
    void remove();
}
```

This is another way that's *technically speaking* not an inner class, but some people will look at you funny if you say that:

```
class MyIterable implements Iterable {
    public Iterator iterator() {
        return new MyIterator();
    }

    static class MyIterator {
        public boolean hasNext() {...}
        public Object next() {...}
        void remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you implement [Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html), you can then use *for:each* loop syntax:

> Implementing this interface allows an object to be the target of the
>   "foreach" statement.

[Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) is a *generic interface*, you should implement the method it contains:

```
public class MyIterable<E> implements Iterable<E>{
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {    // <--- Implement me!
        return new CustomIterator<E>();
    }
}
```

And then, for example, you can do something like this:

```
public class CustomIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
    public boolean hasNext() {
         //...
    }

    public T next() {
        //...
    }

    public void remove() {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1769083 no, it could return an existing class or top level class that implements `Iterator<T>`. You could even implement Iterable<T> and Iterator<T> in the same class, but if you do that within my company you won't survive for long :)

Comment: @owlstead My company will iterate over my dead body if I do it that way :D

Comment: I guess I'm just confused over what is meant when it says to do this without using an inner-iterator class.

Comment: @user1769083 If you don't have the class inside another class, it's not an inner class. You can have a class that implements `Iterable` without having it within another class, so it won't be an *inner class*.

Comment: I don't know if I am over thinking it or what, but I am completely confused now.  The way this assignment works is that I write this program, SBag, and there is an SBagDriver program that tests out all the methods and things I am supposed to do.  Within SBag I am supposed to specifically implement Iterable<Item> without using an inner-iterable class for SBag.  I guess my confusion lies in where I implement the methods of the iterable vs iterator.  In the SBag class I would implement the iterable<item> like I have.

Comment: From the Sbag class I would implement the iterator() method and that would point to a new separate class in the same file that has the hasNext(), next(), and remove() methods.

Answer (score 0):

While [this answer] provides the regular syntax for `Iterable` implementations, an `Iterator` can be useful without an `Iterable`-implementing class. For example:

```
public class DoesntIterate{

public void coolMethod(){
//Do stuff
Iterator iter = getMyIterator();
   while(iter.hasNext()){
   //Do stuff with iter.next()
   }
}

private Iterator getMyIterator(){
   return new MyIterator();
}

private class MyIterator implements Iterator{
...
}

}
```

With this sort of paradigm, it's conceivable that you might use **different iterators for different purposes** all within the same class.

From an OOP perspective, you should never be making a class `implement Iterable` when it doesn't make sense for that to be an class *on which* you would iterate (i.e. if the class is not a data/storage structure).